# Uniform Convegence of differentiable polynomials to differentiable functon

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuously different on $[0,1]$ show that there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ converging to $f$ such that $p_{n}^\prime$ converges uniformly to $f^\prime$.

**Scratch Idea** Since $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$, $f^\prime$ is continuous. Then by Weierstrass theorem, there is a sequence of polynomials (call it $k_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. Hence, set $\epsilon >0$, 
$$ |k_n - f^\prime|_{\infty} < \epsilon$$

Since a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, we have 
$$|p_n - f|_{\infty} < \epsilon $$

I suppose that I have to show $$ |p_{n}^\prime - f^\prime| < \epsilon $$. But I don't know how to connect with my above two statements and what I have to prove.

Helps are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_n(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x k_n(t)\, dt$, $x\in [0,1]$. Then $p_n$ is a sequence of polynomials on $[0,1]$. For all $x\in [0,1]$,

$$|p_n(x) - f(x)| = \left|\int_0^x[k_n(t) - f'(t)]\, dt\right| \le \int_0^x |k_n(t) - f'(t)|\, dt \le \|k_n - f'\|_\infty.$$

Thus

$$\|p_n - f\|_\infty \le \|k_n - f'\|_\infty \to 0\quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty.$$

Hence, $p_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Moreover, since $p_n' = k_n$ and $k_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, then $p_n' \to f'$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the $k_n$ you are using is the one I mentioned in the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's the same one.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just did not know how to connect the facts I had.